# What are the degree markers on the tail of this MD-10 for?

Tags: control-surfaces, horizontal-stabilizer, aircraft-marking, dc-10

I took this picture of of Orbis's McDonnell Douglas MD-10-30. Tail: N330AU.

[image]

What purpose do the 0 and 2 degree markers serve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the angle of the horizontal stabilizer marked on the fuselage?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/72672/why-is-the-angle-of-the-horizontal-stabilizer-marked-on-the-fuselage) Not the most thorough answers, but since it's the same question, new answers should go there.

Comment: It is there so the pilots can check the stab trim via the wingtip mirrors.

Answer (score 2):

This tells the maintenance mechanics what trim state the elevator is in without having to run the pitch trim motor back and forth from the cockpit.

Comment: I think you meant stabilizer not elevator. Also I don't follow the logic: let's assume there are no markings, how does running the motor/actuator back and forth help?

Comment: OK, call it the stabilizer. mechanic doesn't know the status of pitch trim. climbs into the cockpit, runs the pitch trim to the nose up limit, goes back, measures the pitch angle, runs back to cockpit, runs the pitch trim to its nose down limit, goes back and measures the pitch angle. Or (s)he looks at the index mark on the fuselage.